# How to select only when Mathematica manages to find a solution?

Tags: equation-solving, filtering

I have a list of solutions from a LinearSolve :

```
Table[LinearSolve[mat, vect], {x0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}, {x1, 0.4, 0.7, 
  0.1}, {w0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1}, {w1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}]
```

Sometimes Mathematica manages to find a solution, sometimes not.

How could I select only the results and not all the failures in :

```
{{{0.45, 0.1, 0.1, 
   0.45, {{0.030407}, {1.12655}, {0.030407}, {-1.86933}, {-1.}, \
{0.}}}, {0.45, 0.1, 0.2, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.449, 0.248506, 0.099, 0.044999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.10925, -0.796506, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -0.796506, -4.60517, -0.449, -0.198, 0}, {0.199, 
      0.39982, 0.449, 0.089999, 0.202499, 0}, {-5.29832, -1.04782, 
      0, -0.449, 0, 0}, {0, -1.04782, -6.10925, -0.199, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.202499}, {-0.898}, {0}, {0.039999}, {-0.398}, {0}}]}, \
{0.45, 0.1, 0.3, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.449, 0.248506, 0.099, 0.044999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.10925, -0.796506, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -0.796506, -4.60517, -0.449, -0.198, 0}, {0.299, 
      0.636292, 0.449, 0.134999, 0.202499, 0}, {-5.70378, -1.38429, 
      0, -0.449, 0, 0}, {0, -1.38429, -6.10925, -0.299, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.202499}, {-0.898}, {0}, {0.089999}, {-0.598}, {0}}]}}, \
{{0.55, 0.1, 0.1, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.549, 0.39982, 0.099, 0.054999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.30992, -1.04782, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -1.04782, -4.60517, -0.549, -0.198, 0}, {0.099, 
      0.248506, 0.449, 0.044999, 0.202499, 0}, {-4.60517, -0.796506, 
      0, -0.449, 0, 0}, {0, -0.796506, -6.10925, -0.099, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.302499}, {-1.098}, {0}, {0.009999}, {-0.198}, {0}}]}, \
{0.55, 0.1, 0.2, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.549, 0.39982, 0.099, 0.054999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.30992, -1.04782, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -1.04782, -4.60517, -0.549, -0.198, 0}, {0.199, 0.39982,
       0.449, 0.089999, 0.202499, 0}, {-5.29832, -1.04782, 0, -0.449, 
      0, 0}, {0, -1.04782, -6.10925, -0.199, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.302499}, {-1.098}, {0}, {0.039999}, {-0.398}, {0}}]}, \
{0.55, 0.1, 0.3, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.549, 0.39982, 0.099, 0.054999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.30992, -1.04782, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -1.04782, -4.60517, -0.549, -0.198, 0}, {0.299, 
      0.636292, 0.449, 0.134999, 0.202499, 0}, {-5.70378, -1.38429, 
      0, -0.449, 0, 0}, {0, -1.38429, -6.10925, -0.299, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.302499}, {-1.098}, {0}, {0.089999}, {-0.598}, {0}}]}}, \
{{0.65, 0.1, 0.1, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.649, 0.636292, 0.099, 0.064999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.47697, -1.38429, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -1.38429, -4.60517, -0.649, -0.198, 0}, {0.099, 
      0.248506, 0.449, 0.044999, 0.202499, 0}, {-4.60517, -0.796506, 
      0, -0.449, 0, 0}, {0, -0.796506, -6.10925, -0.099, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.422499}, {-1.298}, {0}, {0.009999}, {-0.198}, {0}}]}, \
{0.65, 0.1, 0.2, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.649, 0.636292, 0.099, 0.064999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.47697, -1.38429, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -1.38429, -4.60517, -0.649, -0.198, 0}, {0.199, 0.39982,
       0.449, 0.089999, 0.202499, 0}, {-5.29832, -1.04782, 0, -0.449, 
      0, 0}, {0, -1.04782, -6.10925, -0.199, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.422499}, {-1.298}, {0}, {0.039999}, {-0.398}, {0}}]}, \
{0.65, 0.1, 0.3, 0.45, 
   LinearSolve[{{0.649, 0.636292, 0.099, 0.064999, 0.009999, 
      0}, {-6.47697, -1.38429, 0, -0.099, 0, 
      0}, {0, -1.38429, -4.60517, -0.649, -0.198, 0}, {0.299, 
      0.636292, 0.449, 0.134999, 0.202499, 0}, {-5.70378, -1.38429, 
      0, -0.449, 0, 0}, {0, -1.38429, -6.10925, -0.299, -0.898, 
      0}}, {{0.422499}, {-1.298}, {0}, {0.089999}, {-0.598}, {0}}]}}}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is the output you need in what you posted? And would it be possible to provide a toy example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DeleteCases[output, _?(Head[#] == LinearSolve &), -1]
```